# Why is the empty theory with a single binary function companionable?

Tags: model-theory

I was looking around on the map of the universe and came across [this entry](http://forkinganddividing.com/#_02_57). I checked the provided source for more information, but it didn't seem to actually say anything about this theory from a quick source. I then tried to prove that this theory existed myself, but I am struggling to figure out what the existentially closed models are, much less if they form an elementary class.

Comment: This paper https://users.math.cas.cz/~jerabek/papers/ec.pdf gives, for every language, an explicit axiomatiziation of the model completion of the empty theory.  See Section 3.  I suppose that one could extract from that proof a simpler set of axioms in the specific case of a language with just one function symbol, but I haven't attempted to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *Generic expansion and Skolemization in NSOP$_1$ theories* by Kruckman and Ramsey ([journal DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2018.04.003), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06616)) there is Theorem 3.8, which is exactly what you are looking for I think. Given any language $L$ it constructs a theory $T^\emptyset_L$ that is the model companion of the empty $L$-theory.

Moreover, given your original motivation, you might be interested in Corollary 3.13: it establishes that the theory is NSOP$_1$ and describes Kim-independence in the theory (over models). Namely: $a$ is Kim-independent from $b$ over $M$ iff $\operatorname{acl}(Ma) \cap \operatorname{acl}(Mb) = \operatorname{acl}(M)$.

Finally, Proposition 3.14 shows that if $L$ contains an $n$-ary function symbol (with $n \geq 2$) then $T^\emptyset_L$ has TP$_2$ and is thus not simple. In particular this establishes the exact position in the map of the theory you asked about.

---

Part of the initial confusion was due to a wrong link, which should have linked to the abovementioned paper (and it now does). Also, to make sure proper credit is given I would like to refer to the comment of Alex Kruckman below, where he points out that their results are inspired by a preprint of Emil Jerabek.

Comment: It turns out that the reference on forkinganddividing.com actually *is* to my paper with Nick: it's [52] on the [reference list](http://forkinganddividing.com/references.pdf). The error is that the hyperlink in the entry points to the wrong paper. I'll ask Gabe to fix it.

Comment: Also, I want to make sure proper credit is given: as we point out in the introduction, our paper was directly inspired by a preprint by Emil Jerabek, which turned into the paper Chris Eagle linked to in the comment above. In the preprint, Jerabek had already axiomatized the model companion and proved it is NSOP3 - and he later independently proved that it is NSOP1.

Comment: Apologies for the error. It is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks both, I have edited the final paragraph of my answer accordingly.